# React onClick function not executing when DEPLOYED

Tags: reactjs

I created a function to change the class of the div tag on clicking on an image. Superficially it is just displaying a dropdown menu when clicked on the hamburger icon. This is working in development mode but not in deployment mode when deployed on a static server.

```
import React, { useState }  from 'react';
import Hamberger from '../media/ohUdyBk.png';
import Jetnet from '../media/jetnet.png';

function Topbar() {

  const [statusDropdown, setState] = useState("Hiddenbanner");

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="Menubar">
        <span>
          <img onClick={() => statusDropdown === "Hiddenbanner" ? setState("Backbanner") : setState("Hiddenbanner")} src={Hamberger} alt="hamberger" className="Hamberger" style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} />
        </span>
        <span>
          <img src={Jetnet} alt="jetnet" className="Jetnet" style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} />
        </span>
      </div>
      <span className={statusDropdown}>
        <div>
        <a href="https://google.com">Link1</a>
        </div>
        <div>
        <a href="https://google.com">Link1</a>
        </div>
        <div>
        <a href="https://google.com">Link1</a>
        </div>
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Topbar;
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "secure_portal",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": ".",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-transition-group": "^1.2.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should slightly change the approach to a better toggle. try this

```
const [showHiddenBanner, setShowHiddenBanner] = useState(true);

<img onClick={() => showHiddenBanner(!showHiddenBanner} src={Hamberger} alt="hamberger" className="Hamberger" style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} />
```

then in your code you can do this

```
{ showHiddenBanner ? <HiddenBanner /> : <DisplaySomethingElse />
```

Comment: I tried your coding style.. still it is not working in static deployement server...

Comment: are you getting any errors when you click? or warnings? also where are you hosting it?

Comment: I am not getting any error... I am hosting it on serve -s build

Comment: i have attached my package.json too

Comment: all the rest of your code looks fine. I would suggest putting some console.logs in and then deploying them or using breakpoints to see if everything is as you'd expect. it's hard to give more help at the moment. let me know if you get a chance to do this and anything else looks weird. is the rest of the app rendering fine once deployed?